# jQuery checking checkboxes does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to implement a "Select All" checkbox on an HTML form using JQuery 1.9.1.  As far as I can tell, it should be as simple as using **.prop** to check or uncheck a checkbox, but nothing I try seems to work.

Please see below for what I have tried, I've commented out some failed attempts out and I cannot get this to work for even one checkbox.  What is the correct way to do this?  Am I missing something, possibly in the HTML?

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_select_all" name="cb_select_all" value="t" />
<label for="cb_select_all"><b>Select All</b>
</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" class="cb_all" value="t" />
<label for="cb1">1 test</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" class="cb_all" value="t" />
<label for="cb2">2 test</label>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cb_select_all").change(cb_select_all_onchange);
}); //end $(document).ready

function cb_select_all_onchange() {
    if ($("#cb_select_all").checked) {
        //$("#cb1").prop("checked", true);
        //$(".cb_all").each(function(){ this.checked = true; });
        //document.getElementById("cb1").checked = true;
        $(".cb_all").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#cb1").prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLnb5qed/5/

Thanks,
jdt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `if` to this

```
if ($("#cb_select_all")[0].checked) { }
```

( or ) `if ($("#cb_select_all").is(":checked")) { }` 
The problem is the first one is a property of native element and not jQuery object. Accessing it by an index gives you the ability to use that property. The second way is the jQuery way.

Comment: You're using an ID selector, `[0]` is not needed unless there is illegal HTML going on. Also, `.checked` is a DOM property, not a jQuery property.

Comment: @SterlingArcher well, you seriously have to know things, I suppose. I too said `.checked` is a DOM property.

Comment: Oops, I completely missed that! You're right, my bad!

Comment: @SterlingArcher happens! :)

Comment: Just to add a bit of extra info, using the `element[0].checked` technique is by far the most efficient way to do this: http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/5

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#cb_select_all").is(':checked');
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this code solves the original poster's question? Code-only answers are generally frowned upon without explanation.

Comment: That's not the point, these types of answers are flagged, which is why it received the comment. Please elaborate on your answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cb_select_all").change(function () {
            if ($("#cb_select_all").prop("checked") == true) {
                $('.cb_all').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('.cb_all').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

What happens:

```
Check if the "cb_select_all" checkbox changes state
if the "checked" state is set to true
   check all "cb_all" checkboxes
else
   uncheck all "cb_all" checkboxes
```